# How to optimize query which has to get last 5 rows with joined table

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have two tables events and user_device. `events` and `user_device` has a common field `device_id`.

`user_device` table has fields `user_id` and `device_id`. Basically, user_device table holding all devices belongs to users.

`events` table holding all events belongs to devices.

Now I want to get last 5 alerts for a specific user.

So I have made a query by joining both tables like below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN user_device ON user_device.deviceid=events.deviceid 
WHERE user_device.userid=101 
ORDER BY events.id DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

events table has more than 4 million records. This query takes 30 seconds to return the results.

If I remove **ORDER BY**, the query takes only two seconds.

How can I optimize this?

Comment: if you have get particular record so write manually and remove `*` from query

Comment: Please read this, paying special attention to the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please [edit] your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

**First**: don't use `SELECT *`. Instead, give the names of the columns you want.

**Second**: You're looking for an equality match on `user_device.userid`. So you need an index on `user_device` starting with the `userid` column. You're then employing the value of `deviceid` in that same table. So, create this index. It's called a [covering index](https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727).

```
 ALTER TABLE user_device ADD INDEX x_user_device (userid, deviceid);
```

**Third**: You're looking up rows in `events` by `deviceid`, then ordering by `id`. So you need another [covering index](https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727) on those two columns.

```
 ALTER TABLE events ADD INDEX x_device_id (deviceid, id);
```

**Fourth**: you mention a column from your LEFT JOINed table in a WHERE clause. That converts the LEFT JOIN to an ordinary inner JOIN. So use JOIN.

**Fifth**:  `SELECT * ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT` is a notorious performance antipattern. Why? It has to order a whole mess of records, just to discard all but a few.  Try this instead.  First get the relevant `events.id` values with a subquery.

```
          SELECT events.id
            FROM events
            JOIN user_device ON user_device.deviceid=events.deviceid
           WHERE user_device.userid=101
           ORDER BY events.id DESC
           LIMIT 5
```

Test that subquery. It should give you five relevant event id values, and it should do it very quickly indeed.  Then use this subquery to look up the details you need from your two tables:

```
SELECT events.*, user_device.*      /* not optimal. list only the columns you need */
  FROM (
          SELECT events.id
            FROM events
            JOIN user_device ON user_device.deviceid=events.deviceid
           WHERE user_device.userid=101
           ORDER BY events.id DESC
           LIMIT 5
       ) sel 
  JOIN events ON sel.id = events.id
  JOIN user_device ON events.deviceid = user_device.deviceid
```

This is called the deferred join query pattern. It does all the ordering on just a pile of `id` values, then pulls out only a few records.

This should help you keep performance in check as your database grows.

Comment: Thank You @O.Jones. This explanation helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this takes longer than usual is most likely because of lack of indexes on the table. Add an indexes for deviceId and userId will help a lot with the speed of the query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN user_device ON user_device.**deviceid**=events.**deviceid** 
WHERE user_device.**userid**=101 
ORDER BY events.id DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Bold text requires indexes for quick 'hooks'. the Order by doesn't requre an index.

Comment: Thanks @naveed-ramzan